# How to get a response from a different domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to get the response text from google.com and display it. (using alert or whatever). I know there are problems with domains and others. anyone have any idea of getting it. I searched a lot but still stuck in there :( please help

Comment: can you explain further?

Comment: means?? I just want to get the response text.

Comment: If you're talking about ajax, google about `same origin policy`.

Comment: ya. It doesn't matter with or without ajax. if i can get the response text anyhow thats all I need thanks bro

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup a `gateway`between the remote site and your script.

For example, create a simple PHP function where you fetch the desired address and return the ouput:

```
<?php

function getRemoteContent($address) {
 header("Content-Type: text/html");

 $content = file_get_contents($address);
 return $content;
}

print getRemoteContent($_GET['url']);
?>
```

After, you need to link your Ajax action to this function (for example, if your file is localised in a file called `remote.php`

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'remote.php',
 data: {url: 'http://www.google.fr'},
 success: function(data) {
   alert (data);
 },
 error: function() {
   alert ('oups');
 }
});
```

Note: untested and very simple example ;)

> **Note** I suggest the read of [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/643573/Retrieve-any-web-content-via-AJAX-from-any-URL-dom) for further explanation

Comment: `getRemoteContent` performs a query from the server side (you need this PHP "gaterway") to fetch the remote website content.
You can't access to remote domains (which not allowing explicitly your domain queries) directly from Javascript. PS: sry for my english

Comment: thanks bro. but something wrong. what is the use of print getRemoteContent??(i removed it and code got ok) and in $ajax, what are 2 urls. 1st url for our home page ryt? and when i inserted it the alert displays the source of the given page not the page given by data: {url: 'http://www.google.fr'} then i set that url to google.com but then alert('oups') displayed dnt knw whats going on there